# error code -1005 network connection is lost after i dismiss a UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, NetConfig.ActionSaveEditCustomerInfo, parameters: parameters, encoding: .URLEncodedInURL, headers: header).responseJSON() {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            print(response.result.value)
            if let json = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,String> {

                if json["status"] == "1" {
                    print("ok")

                    let alertOk = UIAlertController(title: "demoOk", message: "Ok", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {
                        (action) in
                        alertOk.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    alertOk.addAction(okAction)
                    self.presentViewController(alertOk, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }else {
                    let alertFail = UIAlertController(title: "Failure", message: "failure", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {
                        (action) in
                        alertFail.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    alertFail.addAction(okAction)
                    self.presentViewController(alertFail, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }else {
            print("error info : \(response.result.error)")
        }
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        self.saveBar.enabled = true
    }
}
```

After this code, the alert will be displayed on the screen, then my first `http` request must be failed, and I receive this error:

```
NSLocalizedDescription = The network connection was lost
```

I'm not sure what is causing this.

Comment: What is flow you call this function? And where you get `NSLocalizedDescription`?

Comment: a click event will call this function  , as I click okAction  the alert will dismiss ,then  I send a click event once again  ，the connection was lost , then I send third click event ，the request is ok @vien vu

Comment: Do you try your request with postMan? What happen if you request two times? I try your function with my link it normal :|

Comment: I have found where is the problem , this code has no issue. the reason of this is the server close this connection after back response. but the library still reuse that connection  @vien vu   taks